# Definition of the different DNA regions

Tags: genomics, variant

Reading from Oshima et al. (2016):

> We identified 3,868 noncoding mutations including 394 located <5 Kb downstream, 1,762 intergenic, 1,621 intronic, 81 <5 Kb upstream, 7 UTR 3′, 2 UTR 5′, and 1 intragenic variants.

How upstream, downstream and intragenic variants are defined? Shouldn't intragenic variants be classified within intronic variants, and upstream/downstream within intergenic variants?

**Edit**: By adding the different numbers it seems they are mutual exclusive. While upstream/downstream variants can be defined as intergenic variants that lie close to genes, I haven't found a definition to tell the intragenic variants from the intronic ones.

**Edit 2**: The only explanation I could think of for intragenic variant is that it is located in a coding region which is not transcribed due to alternative splicing. Can it be possible?

- Oshima, Koichi, et al. "[Mutational landscape, clonal evolution patterns, and role of RAS mutations in relapsed acute lymphoblastic leukemia.](http://www.pnas.org/content/113/40/11306.full)" Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences (2016): 201608420.

Comment: You could try sending them a quick email.

Answer (score 1):

We can take a look at the following picture (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene#Structure_and_function)):

[image: Gene structure]

The regions are then:

- intergenic: everything outside of the shown gene region
- <5 Kb downstream: outside of the transcribed region, but possibly part of the promoter or an enhancer (yellow boxes before coding region).
- UTR 5′: in the transcribed region, but not part of the coding region, as shown in the picture (blue box before coding region).
- intronic: In the Introns, as shown in the picture (grey boxes)
- intragenic: These have to be mutations inside the coding region (red boxes), which is confusing since the authors specifically describe them as 'non-coding' mutations. If you read that as 'mutations that don't change the protein sequence', these could be [silent mutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_mutation)
- UTR 3′: in the transcribed region, but not part of the coding region, as shown in the picture (blue box after coding region)
- <5 Kb upstream: outside of the transcribed region, but possibly part of an enhancer (yellow boxes after coding region)

Comment: Intragenic is not coding (as it's CDS and introns). Intragenic is region from TSS to TTS.

Comment: @SEwontLetMeDeleteProfile can you elaborate more on that? Also, what is a TTS?

Answer (score 1):

The [Sequence Ontology](http://www.sequenceontology.org/) project defines an intragenic variant as "A variant that occurs within a gene but falls outside of all transcript features. This occurs when alternate transcripts of a gene do not share overlapping sequence." [source](http://sequenceontology.org/browser/current_svn/term/SO:0002011)

Intragenic means the variant is located within the same gene, which only implies that the sequence analysis assigned a certain variant to a gene. So, there is incomplete data regarding the gene product (such as different splice forms).

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the mutation locations here:  http://grch37.ensembl.org/index.html